Realistic simulation for USRP transmission
I want to simulate a QPSK transmission over two USRP to test some DSP algorithms in my computer with MATLAB. Hence, I would like to include every impairment USRP and the environment has. The center frequency can be selected as 433 MHz or 2.4 GHz. Also, I am planning to simulate transmission at 100 ksps with a root raised cosine filter (so bandwidth is around 125 kHz). I want to simulate two stationary USRP's in a single room without any moving object.
I have 5 impairment effects in my mind to implement, which are:

Additive Gaussian noise
DC signal
Carrier frequency offset
Fading Channel (Rayleigh, Rician)
Clock frequency offset between Tx and Rx
Fractional delay

Are the effects above are enough for realistic simulation? If not, what effect should I include?
Thanks.

you'll have to tell us a significant amount more about the transmission you're planning to do: at the very least, center frequency and bandwidth would be necessary to know. Then you need to tell us in which scenario your receiver and transmitter are: a high-speed train to fixed tunnel infrastructure connection has to deal with different channel effects than a human moving indoors talking to the wifi access point in the next room.

hi, center frequency can be selected as 433 MHz or 2.4 GHz. Also, I am planning to simulate transmission at 100 ksps with a root raised cosine filter (so bandwidth is around 125 kHz). I want to simulate two stationary USRP's in a single room without any moving object. Does it help?

It helps a lot! :) For me to be able to write an answer: would you edit your question please and include the info that you just gave me in the question?

"Indoors" means that maximum path length differences (between, say a path that is directly from the transmit to the receive antenna and a path that reflects a couple of times) are smaller than say 50m. That means that for a 125 kHz wide channel, the shortest and longest paths will effectively be indistinguishable: you don't have to care about multipath propagation.
But: Those are two very different frequencies, and consequently two pretty different propagation problems! The attenuation will be drastically different (see: path loss coefficient).
At 2.4 GHz (which is the higher of both frequencies, and thus more subject to Doppler shifts), a sprinting person (~ 10m/s) would cause a Doppler shift of 80 Hz.

I can't tell you whether that's a problem for your system! You can figure that yourself: For the duration in between your receiver estimating the phase of the transmission, can you tolerate the phase rotating at a speed of $2\pi/80\,\frac{1}{\text{s}}$?

For example, assume you transmit frames with a preamble, so that the receiver can know the phase of the transmission. If your frame is now 100 ms long, then the phase of the last symbol will be $\frac{\pi}{4}$ shifted relative to the first one. That's not much of a problem for BPSK transmission, but it would make 16-PSK transmission completely impossible, and 64 QAM would have a lot of bit errors. You might want to have phase recovery running on the received symbols, in either case, anyways, though, since oscillator stability is a problem even without Doppler.
Assuming "indoor" also assumes limited  near/far problems, we can assume that dynamic range doesn't matter as much, and that modelling the system as continuous-valued is good enough, and we don't have to care about quantization effects.
Also, it probably means "low power"; and hence, we don't have to incorporate nonlinear amplifier effects.
You might want to model interferers when you're in an unlicensed band, not just white noise. (and note that "Gaussian" does not imply "white", even if that is probably what you meant to imply).
Depending on how long your observations are, your channel will change: obviously, someone walking by the antenna will change the amount of power reaching you! Also, the phase is affected. So, your fading model might have to be time-variant.

To further enhance realism, you could also consider these additional impairments:

Phase Noise
Multipath Delays and Doppler Spread
IQ Imbalance

